# How to get the URI to a specified location?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I need your help with a little problem I'm finding with my app.

In my app, I use this code to copy all the contents of the asset folder, in a folder that I create myself.

```
File wallpaperDirectory = new File("/sdcard/Wallpaper/");
    wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();

    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    String[] files = null;
    try {
        files = assetManager.list("");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
    }
    for(String filename : files) {
        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
          in = assetManager.open(filename);
          out = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/Wallpaper/" + filename);
          copyFile(in, out);
          in.close();
          in = null;
          out.flush();
          out.close();
          out = null;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
        }       
}

private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
      out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

Now I need the 'URI to this folder (/sdcard/Wallpaper/), that i have created, as you get? thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get Uri of Particular Folder on SDcard.

```
String sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

Uri.fromFile(new File(sdcard+"/Wallpaper/"));
```

Or

```
Uri.parse(sdcard+"/Wallpaper/")
```

Comment: I need the 'uri to the folder, not to a specific file contained in it. because, according to my idea, then I have to get the files in this path randomly maybe using a cursor

Comment: Great answer, to my surprise, this still works! Even with the modern storage framework.

Answer (score 1):

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/Wallpaper/"));
```

or

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("/sdcard/Wallpaper/");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Get the File path

```
File path = "/sdcard/Wallpaper/";
```

Convert the file path in to Uri by the following code

```
Uri imageurl = Uri.fromFile(path);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `public static Uri fromFile (File file)` method from `android.net.Uri`.